# short Text RPG, give me some advice

Tags: c++

Here is the code of TEXT based short rpg I made.
Feel free to give any idea to improve or change the code.
Or you can give me some challenge to work on so that I can learn from that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define NAME_SIZE 30

class Player
{
private:
    char strPlayerName[NAME_SIZE];
    int nSaveNum;
    int nDamage;
    int nHP;
    int nGold;
public:
    Player() = default;
    Player(char* pName, int Class, int Damage, int HP, int Gold)
        : nSaveNum(Class), nDamage(Damage), nHP(HP), nGold(Gold)
    {
        strcpy_s(strPlayerName, pName);
    }
    Player(const Player& T)
    {
        strcpy_s(strPlayerName, T.strPlayerName);
        nSaveNum = T.nSaveNum;
        nDamage = T.nDamage;
        nHP = T.nHP;
        nGold = T.nGold;
    }
    void setName(char* pName)
    {
        strcpy_s(strPlayerName, pName);
    }
    void setSaveNum(int num) { nSaveNum = num; }
    void setDamage(int Damage) { nDamage = Damage; }
    void setHP(int HP) { nHP = HP; }
    void setGold(int Gold) { nGold = Gold; }
    void setBattleGold(int Gold) { nGold += Gold; }
    void setStoreDamage(int HP) { nHP += HP; }
    void setStoreHP(int HP) { nHP += HP; }
    void setStoreGold(int Gold) { nGold -= Gold; }
    char* getName() { return strPlayerName; }
    int getSaveNum() const { return nSaveNum; }
    int getDamage() const { return nDamage; }
    int getHP() const { return nHP; }
    int getGold() const { return nGold; }   
    void addCharacter()
    {
        std::cout << "NAME : ";
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cin.getline(strPlayerName, NAME_SIZE);
        std::cout << "NUMBER : ";
        std::cin >> nSaveNum;
        nDamage = 5;
        nHP = 100;
        nGold = 0;
    }
    void showPlayer() const
    {
        std::cout << strPlayerName << " / " << nSaveNum << " / " << nDamage << " / " << nHP << " / " << nGold << std::endl;
    }
};

class Monster
{
private:
    char strMonsterName[NAME_SIZE];
    int nDamage;
    int nHP;
    int nGold;
public:
    Monster(char* pName, int Damage, int HP, int Gold)
        : nDamage(Damage), nHP(HP), nGold(Gold)
    {
        strcpy_s(strMonsterName, pName);
    }
    void setHP(int HP) { nHP = HP; }
    char* getName() { return strMonsterName; }
    int getDamage() const { return nDamage; }
    int getHP() const { return nHP; }
    int getGold() const { return nGold; }
    void showMonster() const
    {
        std::cout << strMonsterName << " / " << nDamage << " / " << nHP << " / " << nGold << std::endl;
    }
};

void newCharacter(Player& player)
{
    std::ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("Save.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
    player.addCharacter();
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&player), sizeof(Player));
    outFile.close();
}

Player selectCharacter(int n)
{
    Player player, tmp;
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("Save.dat", std::ios::binary);
    if (!inFile)
    {
        throw "File could not be open...";
    }
    inFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    while (inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&player), sizeof(Player)))
    {
        if (player.getSaveNum() == n)
        {
            tmp.setName(player.getName());
            tmp.setSaveNum(player.getSaveNum());
            tmp.setHP(player.getHP());
            tmp.setDamage(player.getDamage());
            tmp.setGold(player.getGold());
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
    std::cout << "Selection Complete" << std::endl;

    return tmp;
}

void showAll()
{
    Player player;
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("Save.dat", std::ios::binary);
    if (!inFile)
    {
        std::cout << "File could not be open...";
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "CHARACTER LIST" << std::endl;
    while (inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&player), sizeof(Player)))
    {
        player.showPlayer();
    }
    inFile.close();
}
void saveCharacter(Player& p, int n)
{
    bool found = false;
    Player player;
    std::fstream File;
    File.open("Save.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
    if (!File)
    {
        std::cout << "File coud not be open...";
    }
    while (!File.eof() && found == false)
    {
        File.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&player), sizeof(Player));
        if (player.getSaveNum() == n)
        {
            player.setName(p.getName());
            player.setSaveNum(p.getSaveNum());
            player.setHP(p.getHP());
            player.setDamage(p.getDamage());
            player.setGold(p.getGold());

            int pos = (-1) * static_cast<int>(sizeof(Player));
            File.seekp(pos, std::ios::cur);
            File.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&player), sizeof(Player));
            std::cout << "Save Updated";
            found = true;
        }
    }
}

void delete_character(int n)
{
    Player player;
    std::ifstream inFile;
    std::ofstream outFile;
    inFile.open("Save.dat", std::ios::binary);
    if (!inFile)
    {
        std::cout << "File could not be open...";
        return;
    }
    outFile.open("Temp.dat", std::ios::binary);
    inFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    while (inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&player), sizeof(Player)))
    {
        if (player.getSaveNum() != n)
        {
            outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&player), sizeof(Player));
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
    remove("Save.dat");
    rename("Temp.dat", "Save.dat");
    std::cout << "Record Deleted" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    char strName[NAME_SIZE];

    Player p;

    strcpy_s(strName, "GOBLIN");
    Monster m0(strName, 2, 50, 10);

    strcpy_s(strName, "TROLL");
    Monster m1(strName, 20, 700, 100);

    strcpy_s(strName, "DRAGON");
    Monster m2(strName, 90, 5000, 1000);

    while (true)
    {
        system("cls");

        std::cout << "\t01.NEW" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\t02.SAVE LIST" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\t03.PLAY" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\t04.DELETE SAVE FILE" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\t05.EXIT" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\tSELECT : ";
        int nMenu;
        std::cin >> nMenu;

        if (nMenu == 5)
            break;

        switch (nMenu)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            newCharacter(p);
        }
            break;
        case 2:
        {
            showAll();
            std::cout << "SELECT NUMBER : ";
            std::cin >> nMenu;
            Player tmp(selectCharacter(nMenu));
            strcpy_s(strName, tmp.getName());
            p.setName(strName);
            p.setSaveNum(tmp.getSaveNum());
            p.setDamage(tmp.getDamage());
            p.setHP(tmp.getHP());
            p.setGold(tmp.getGold());
        }
            break;
        case 3:
        {
            while (true)
            {
                system("cls");

                std::cout << "\t01.EASY(GOBLIN)" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "\t02.NORMAL(TROLL)" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "\t03.HARD(DRAGON)" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "\t04.TRAIN" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "\t05.SAVE" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "\t06.EXIT" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "\tSELECT : ";
                std::cin >> nMenu;

                if (nMenu == 6)
                    break;

                switch (nMenu)
                {
                case 1:
                {
                    int tmpPlayerHP = p.getHP();
                    int tmpMonsterHP = m0.getHP();

                    int PlayerHP;
                    int MonsterHP;

                    while (true)
                    {
                        system("cls");

                        if (p.getHP() <= 0)
                            break;
                        if (m0.getHP() <= 0)
                        {
                            p.setBattleGold(m0.getGold());
                            break;
                        }

                        std::cout << "----------- PLAYER ----------" << std::endl;
                        p.showPlayer();

                        std::cout << "----------- MONSTER ----------" << std::endl;
                        m0.showMonster();

                        std::cout << "\t01.FIGHT" << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "\t02.BACK" << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "\tSELECT : ";
                        std::cin >> nMenu;

                        if (nMenu == 2)
                            break;

                        if (nMenu == 1)
                        {
                            PlayerHP = p.getHP() - m0.getDamage();
                            p.setHP(PlayerHP);
                            MonsterHP = m0.getHP() - p.getDamage();
                            m0.setHP(MonsterHP);
                            std::cout << p.getName() << " recieved " << m0.getDamage() << " from " << m0.getName() << std::endl;
                            std::cout << m0.getName() << " recieved " << p.getDamage() << " from " << p.getName() << std::endl;
                        }

                        system("pause");
                    }

                    p.setHP(tmpPlayerHP);
                    m0.setHP(tmpMonsterHP);
                }
                break;
                case 2:
                {
                    int tmpPlayerHP = p.getHP();
                    int tmpMonsterHP = m1.getHP();

                    int PlayerHP;
                    int MonsterHP;

                    while (true)
                    {
                        system("cls");

                        if (p.getHP() <= 0)
                            break;
                        if (m1.getHP() <= 0)
                        {
                            p.setBattleGold(m1.getGold());
                            break;
                        }

                        std::cout << "----------- PLAYER ----------" << std::endl;
                        p.showPlayer();

                        std::cout << "----------- MONSTER ----------" << std::endl;
                        m1.showMonster();

                        std::cout << "\t01.FIGHT" << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "\t02.BACK" << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "\tSELECT : ";
                        std::cin >> nMenu;

                        if (nMenu == 2)
                            break;

                        if (nMenu == 1)
                        {
                            PlayerHP = p.getHP() - m1.getDamage();
                            p.setHP(PlayerHP);
                            MonsterHP = m1.getHP() - p.getDamage();
                            m1.setHP(MonsterHP);
                            std::cout << p.getName() << " recieved " << m1.getDamage() << " from " << m1.getName() << std::endl;
                            std::cout << m1.getName() << " recieved " << p.getDamage() << " from " << p.getName() << std::endl;
                        }

                        system("pause");
                    }

                    p.setHP(tmpPlayerHP);
                    m1.setHP(tmpMonsterHP);
                }
                break;
                case 3:
                {
                    int tmpPlayerHP = p.getHP();
                    int tmpMonsterHP = m2.getHP();

                    int PlayerHP;
                    int MonsterHP;

                    while (true)
                    {
                        system("cls");

                        if (p.getHP() <= 0)
                            break;
                        if (m2.getHP() <= 0)
                        {
                            p.setBattleGold(m2.getGold());
                            break;
                        }

                        std::cout << "----------- PLAYER ----------" << std::endl;
                        p.showPlayer();

                        std::cout << "----------- MONSTER ----------" << std::endl;
                        m2.showMonster();

                        std::cout << "\t01.FIGHT" << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "\t02.BACK" << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "\tSELECT : ";
                        std::cin >> nMenu;

                        if (nMenu == 2)
                            break;

                        if (nMenu == 1)
                        {
                            PlayerHP = p.getHP() - m2.getDamage();
                            p.setHP(PlayerHP);
                            MonsterHP = m2.getHP() - p.getDamage();
                            m2.setHP(MonsterHP);
                            std::cout << p.getName() << " recieved " << m2.getDamage() << " from " << m2.getName() << std::endl;
                            std::cout << m2.getName() << " recieved " << p.getDamage() << " from " << p.getName() << std::endl;
                        }

                        system("pause");
                    }

                    p.setHP(tmpPlayerHP);
                    m2.setHP(tmpMonsterHP);
                }
                break;
                case 4:
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        system("cls");

                        p.showPlayer();

                        std::cout << "\t01.DAMAGE TRAINING(DAMAGE +10)(GOLD -100)" << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "\t02.HEALTH TRAINING(HP +20)(GOLD -150)" << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "\t03.EXIT" << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "\tSELECT : ";
                        std::cin >> nMenu;

                        if (nMenu == 3)
                            break;

                        switch (nMenu)
                        {
                        case 1:
                        {
                            if (p.getGold() < 100)
                            {
                                std::cout << "\t-NOT ENOUGH GOLD-" << std::endl;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                p.setStoreGold(100);
                                p.setDamage(10);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                        case 2:
                        {
                            if (p.getGold() < 150)
                            {
                                std::cout << "\t-NOT ENOUGH GOLD-" << std::endl;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                p.setStoreGold(150);
                                p.setHP(20);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                        default:
                            std::cout << "\t-WRONG INPUT-" << std::endl;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
                case 5:
                {
                    showAll();
                    std::cout << "SELECT NUM : ";
                    std::cin >> nMenu;
                    saveCharacter(p, nMenu);
                }
                    break;
                default:
                    std::cout << "\t-WRONG INPUT-" << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
        case 4:
        {
            showAll();
            std::cout << "SELECT NUMBER TO DELETE" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> nMenu;

            delete_character(nMenu);
        }

            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "-WRONG INPUT-" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any specific problems with this code? If you want a review you should post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Stop using C-style strings(e.g. `char strName[]` in main) and start using C++ strings(`std::string` with `#include <string>`.

Comment: `#define NAME_SIZE 30` is, again, a leftover from C. In C++ we have constexpr: `constexpr std::size_t name_size = 30;`, but this variable is unneeded any way if you switch to `std::string`.

Comment: `while (!File.eof() && found == false)` `File.eof` is `true` after EOF, so you have to check for it after reading(inside the loop itself and `break` if it's false).

Comment: `std::cout << "SOME TEXT" << std::endl;` There's no need to flush here. A simple `\n` will do: `std::cout << "SOME TEXT\n";`

Comment: `system("cls");` is Windows specific. Use `system("clear");` for other OSs(You can check the os with `#if _WIN32` for Windows(This also checks for Win64) and `#else` for everything else with a `#endif` to close it).

Comment: Also your `main` is a bit long. Maybe split it up into multiple functions?